# Significance of the word Cloverfield

Tags: analysis, title, 10-cloverfield-lane, cloverfield, the-cloverfield-paradox

In the Cloverfield franchise every film have Cloverfield in the title but what is the significance of "Cloverfield", In *10 Cloverfield Lane* it was the address of that area but in first film I can't understand its significance. Am I missing something? Does this word have some significance for the franchise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In and Out of Universe Answers:

It's the **name** or codename of the **Government's case** and the out of universe answer is that it's **road/exit** JJ Abrams takes to work at the Santa Monica office.

> **Title**
>
> The film was initially named Cloverfield. This changed several times
>   throughout production before it was decided that the original title
>   would be used. Matt Reeves explained that the title was changed
>   frequently due to the hype caused by the teaser trailer. "That
>   excitement spread to such a degree that we suddenly couldn't use the
>   name anymore. So we started using all these names like Slusho and
>   Cheese. And people always found out what we were doing!" **The
>   director said that "Cloverfield" was the government's case designation
>   for the events caused by the monster, comparing the titling to that of
>   the Manhattan Project. "And it's not a project per se. It's the way
>   that this case has been designated. That's why that is on the trailer,
>   and it becomes clearer in the film. It's how they refer to this
>   phenomenon [or] this case**", **said the director. The film's
>   final title, Cloverfield, is the name of the exit Abrams takes to his
>   Santa Monica office. In turn, the road used to lead to the
>   Santa Monica Airport, which originally bore the name Clover
>   Field.**[citation needed]
>
> One final title, Greyshot, was proposed before the movie was
>   officially titled Cloverfield. The name Greyshot is taken from the
>   archway that the two survivors take shelter under at the end of the
>   movie. Director Reeves said that it was decided not to change the
>   title to Greyshot because the film was already so well known as
>   Cloverfield.
>
> The film received a subtitle in Japan, where it was released as
>   Cloverfield/Hakaisha (クローバーフィールド/HAKAISHA Kurōbāfīrudo/HAKAISHA). The
>   subtitle "Destroyer" was chosen by Abrams and was translated into
>   Japanese as Hakaisha (破壊者 lit. "Destroyer") by Paramount Japan at his
>   request. The subtitle Kishin (鬼神 lit. "Demon[ic] God") was chosen for
>   the manga spin-off, Cloverfield/Kishin, released exclusively in
>   Japan. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloverfield

Comment: For a while the original film was promoted as "Monstrous": http://www.cloverfieldnews.com/2007/07/25/clear-image-of-the-monstrous-cloverfield-poster/ I picked up a copy of the poster at San Diego Comic-Con and have it hanging in my hallway at home. 

Santa Monica Airport was originally named Clover Field in 1923 for a local fighter pilot who died in France during WWI, Greayer Clover: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greayer_Clover

Comment: Cool! Thanks @jeffronicus ! I love extra trivia!!! :)

I kind of wonder if the history of the fighter pilot influenced or inspired Forever Young?? Abrams wrote the script and the short story it's based on...

Answer (score 3):

In the first Cloverfield movie, it was the government/military code name for the "incident" involving other-dimensional aliens. Neutral-sounding code names are used by the military in real life.  Examples: "Fat Man", "Little Boy", and "Tuskegee Experiment".

However, that doesn't explain why that specific name was chosen.

Comment: I think you're conflating "Tuskegee" and "Tunguska", which are very different spots.

Comment: Well, certainly Cloverfield was "the biggest interdimensional cross rip since the Tunguska Blast of 1909." - Ray Stantz, Ghostbusters

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Nice reference!